# Tropo setting voice not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tropo

I am trying to make this line work:

```
tropo.say("Some text","kate");
```

[Documentation](https://www.tropo.com/docs/scripting/international_speaking_other_languages.htm)

But this line breaks the `node.js` app I am writing. If I don't specify the voice then it works fine. For example:

```
tropo.say("Some text");
```

Any tropo guru here that can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked to Scripting docs, but your app is WebAPI.  Here is a script from those docs:

```
var http = require('http');
var tropo_webapi = require('tropo-webapi');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var tropo = new TropoWebAPI();

    // (value, as, name, required, voice)
    tropo.say("Hello, how are you?.", null, null, null, "kate");

    response.end(TropoJSON(tropo));

}).listen(8000);
```

https://www.tropo.com/docs/webapi/international_speaking_other_languages.htm

I believe this was resolved in IRC already, but posting the above for any other users checking it out.

Justin Dupree
Director of Customer Experience
Voxeo Labs

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your parameter wrong. You have posted a link to the [documentation](https://www.tropo.com/docs/scripting/international_speaking_other_languages.htm), which clearly says it should be:

```
say("Some text",{voice:"kate"});
```

Comment: I tried that multiple times and no luck. I have a few tropo.say("some text"); before that one, they all work. When it gets to that it brakes. If I take out the {voice:"kate"} it starts working again. So I instatiate tropo and then do the say like this: var tropo = new TropoWebAPI(); tropo.say("Some text ", {voice:"kate"}); and it brakes.

Comment: @zumzum: Do you have any error log in console (or otherwise) associated with it? Also have you tried any other voices? Possibly for some reason "kate" is not recognized/missing.

Comment: I don't see any error in the log. I'll keep looking but nothing that stands out...I'll try other voices

Comment: @zumzum: If there's no error I'd place my bet the voice resource is not there or otherwise corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The voice Kate is only for British English language. What language are you specifying in your application, if any. The default is U.S English and the female voices you have available are Allison (Default), Susan, Vanessa, Veronica.  Logs should give you a clue as to what is going on. And if you are still stuck ask your question in the [Tropo Forum](https://www.tropo.com/forums/). Voxeo's Extreme Support is pretty good about providing timely and useful assistance.